# MySQL deadlocks in performance_schema.error_log

Tags: mysql

I want to monitor the details of each deadlock in my MySQL database, but the instance is in the cloud, and I don't have the actual log files easily accessible.

My plan was to set the innodb_print_all_deadlocks variable on the instance, and then monitor the performance_schema.error_logs tables.

Unfortunately, all I get is the following... The actual log files have a whole bunch of information about the deadlock, which is what I hoped to capture.

Any assistance would be appreciated. I couldn't find any information about this behavior online.

```
======================================================= 

Logged Date .. .. .. ..: 2024-03-21 16:07:17.564912 
Thread ID .. .. .. .. ..: 0 
Priority .. .. .. .. ..: Note 
Error Code.. .. .. .. ..: MY-012468 
Sub System.. .. .. .. ..: InnoDB 
Data.. .. .. .. .. .. ..: 
Transactions deadlock detected, dumping detailed information. 
======================================================= 

======================================================= 

Logged Date .. .. .. ..: 2024-03-21 16:07:17.564948 
Thread ID .. .. .. .. ..: 0 
Priority .. .. .. .. ..: Note 
Error Code.. .. .. .. ..: MY-012469 
Sub System.. .. .. .. ..: InnoDB 
Data.. .. .. .. .. .. ..: 
*** (1) TRANSACTION: 
======================================================= 

======================================================= 

Logged Date .. .. .. ..: 2024-03-21 16:07:17.564994 
Thread ID .. .. .. .. ..: 0 
Priority .. .. .. .. ..: Note 
Error Code.. .. .. .. ..: MY-012469 
Sub System.. .. .. .. ..: InnoDB 
Data.. .. .. .. .. .. ..: 
*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S): 
======================================================= 

======================================================= 

Logged Date .. .. .. ..: 2024-03-21 16:07:17.565551 
Thread ID .. .. .. .. ..: 0 
Priority .. .. .. .. ..: Note 
Error Code.. .. .. .. ..: MY-012469 
Sub System.. .. .. .. ..: InnoDB 
Data.. .. .. .. .. .. ..: 
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED: 
======================================================= 

======================================================= 

Logged Date .. .. .. ..: 2024-03-21 16:07:17.565622 
Thread ID .. .. .. .. ..: 0 
Priority .. .. .. .. ..: Note 
Error Code.. .. .. .. ..: MY-012469 
Sub System.. .. .. .. ..: InnoDB 
Data.. .. .. .. .. .. ..: 
*** (2) TRANSACTION: 
======================================================= 

======================================================= 

Logged Date .. .. .. ..: 2024-03-21 16:07:17.565659 
Thread ID .. .. .. .. ..: 0 
Priority .. .. .. .. ..: Note 
Error Code.. .. .. .. ..: MY-012469 
Sub System.. .. .. .. ..: InnoDB 
Data.. .. .. .. .. .. ..: 
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S): 
======================================================= 

======================================================= 

Logged Date .. .. .. ..: 2024-03-21 16:07:17.565717 
Thread ID .. .. .. .. ..: 0 
Priority .. .. .. .. ..: Note 
Error Code.. .. .. .. ..: MY-012469 
Sub System.. .. .. .. ..: InnoDB 
Data.. .. .. .. .. .. ..: 
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED: 
======================================================= 

======================================================= 

Logged Date .. .. .. ..: 2024-03-21 16:07:17.566280 
Thread ID .. .. .. .. ..: 0 
Priority .. .. .. .. ..: Note 
Error Code.. .. .. .. ..: MY-012469 
Sub System.. .. .. .. ..: InnoDB 
Data.. .. .. .. .. .. ..: 
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1) 
=======================================================
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.